# How to find window running with own UI thread in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, splash-screen

I have an application that uses a WPF `Window` with an own `Dispatcher` as startup splash window. This splash screen will show information to the user and is a `TopMost` window. I don't want to have it as the `Application.MainWindow` but has to show it before I create the MainWindow...

At any time durring startup or while the application is running, an background worker can detect an fatal error and need to show an message box before the application is terminated. This message box needs to be in front of any open window.

When this error happend while the splash window is visible, the message box is behind the splash screen. Using the splash screen as owner or hide the splash screen whould fix that, but i'm not able to find the splash screen. It's not in the `Application.Current.Windows` collection, I guess because it has a different `Dispatcher`...

Does anyone know how to get the window without passing them to the background worker?

The following code reproduces the problem. It whould be easy to pass all needed references to the worker but it's not what i want do to in the real application.

**App.xaml**

```
  <Application
     x:Class="Sandbox.App"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  >
  </Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
     using System;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Threading;
     using System.Windows;
     using System.Windows.Controls;
     using System.Windows.Media;
     using System.Windows.Threading;

     namespace Sandbox
     {
        public partial class App : Application
        {
           protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
           {
              base.OnStartup(e);

              var closeSplashEvent = App.LanuchSplashScreen();
              App.StartThreadInDifferentAssemblyWithoutRefToThis();

              // ...

              this.MainWindow = new Window { Title="MainWindow",  Width = 800, Height = 600, WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen };
              this.MainWindow.Show();

              //  ...

              App.CloseSplashScreen(closeSplashEvent, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
           }

           private static void StartThreadInDifferentAssemblyWithoutRefToThis()
           {
              ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
              {
                 // ...
                 Thread.Sleep(1000);

                 Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((ThreadStart) delegate
                 {
                    // how to find the splash screen ???
                    var owner = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Title == "SplashScreen") ?? Application.Current.MainWindow;
                    MessageBox.Show(owner, "Should be in front of splash screen!", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                 });
              });
           }

           private static ManualResetEvent LanuchSplashScreen()
           {
              Dispatcher splashDispatcher = null;
              var startupEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
              var splashThread = new Thread(() =>
              {
                 splashDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                 startupEvent.Set();
                 Dispatcher.Run();
              });
              splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
              splashThread.Start();
              startupEvent.WaitOne();

              Window aniSplashWindow = null;
              splashDispatcher.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate
              {
                 aniSplashWindow = new Window
                 {
                    Width = 320, Height = 240, AllowsTransparency = true, Background = Brushes.Transparent, Topmost = true, WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None, WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
                    Title="SplashScreen", Content = new Border { BorderBrush = Brushes.Black, BorderThickness = new Thickness(1), Background = Brushes.White, CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5) }
                 };
                 aniSplashWindow.Show();
              });

              var closeSplashEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
              ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
              {
                 closeSplashEvent.WaitOne();
                 splashDispatcher.Invoke((ThreadStart) delegate
                 {
                    aniSplashWindow.Close();
                    splashDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Normal);
                 });
              });

              return closeSplashEvent;
           }

           private static void CloseSplashScreen(EventWaitHandle closeSplashEvent, TimeSpan closeSplashTimeout)
           {
              ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
              {
                 Thread.Sleep(closeSplashTimeout);
                 closeSplashEvent.Set();
              });
           }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the splash screen exists only once. So why not make it a singleton?

The simplest solution would be to expose it via a global (static) property. Alternatively, (if you create some SplashScreen class), you could export and import it via MEF or some other composition framework.

Comment: I think passing them to the worker would be better than making the splash a static or singleton. Static/Singleton would require that the worker knows the splash screen/app which is a dependency I don't like. MEF or IoC would allow to fix the problem as well.

The point is that i really don't believe it's not possible to find the current active window in a WPF application when it has its own UI thread...